# Keyboard doesn't light up when touchpad is used

Tags: 20.04, keyboard-backlight

So I recently dual booted my system with Ubuntu 20.04. It's a HP Pavilion gaming version. The keyboard I'm talking about is builtin keyboard of the laptop.

While in Windows whenever I used the backlit keyboard (after turning the light on, it turns off when not in use and back on when a key is clicked OR touchpad senses a touch) I would simply light it by touching the pad so I can see where to put my fingers at.

This for some reason doesn't work in Ubuntu and it's minor but very annoying. Is there a solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Edit your question and add information about your laptop / hardware; it may be relevant.

Comment: Did the keyboard come with a driver for Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm sorry I left some info in the post.